# MySQL, Find all employees of a "manager"

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a "manager" that can be assigned to many locations and handles one department in every location. I want a query that can grab all of this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33453c/1

In the example above (in the link) you can see I have calculated how many employees are in each department.

*Managers* and *Employees* are in a table named **staff**, I do not want the query to retrieve the manager record(s). So user_role = "Employee";

I run this as a raw query in *laravel* so I can retrieve them as objects:

```
$employees= DB::query('query goes in here')->get();
```

An example would be the manager with staff_id '5' get every employee that is in all of the locations and department the manager is part of if that makes sense?

My guess would be:

Pseudo

```
First Query SELECT ALL FROM staff, locations and departments where user_role = "employee"

Second Query SELECT ALL FROM staff, locations and departments where manager id=5
```

Remove all results that do not satisfy the second query but join both queries together?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All records that the manager is located in. I know I would need a intersect to grab the id of the manager and his locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.  Left join the manager's department on employee's departments, and get the count of "employee" staff members in each of those departments (even if 0)

Below, shown for manager #2 (you could eliminate the where clause and group by manager id and dept id if you want to see all managers)

```
SELECT dept.name AS dept, loc.address1 AS loc, emp.*
FROM staff AS mgr
INNER JOIN department_staff AS mgr_dept
    ON mgr_dept.staff_id = mgr.staff_id
INNER JOIN departments AS dept
    ON mgr_dept.dept_id = dept.dept_id    
INNER JOIN location_staff AS mgr_loc
    ON mgr_loc.staff_id = mgr.staff_id
INNER JOIN locations AS loc
    ON mgr_loc.loc_id = loc.loc_id    
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT emp.*, dept.dept_id, loc.loc_id
  FROM staff AS emp
  INNER JOIN department_staff AS dept
    ON emp.staff_id = dept.staff_id
  INNER JOIN location_staff AS loc
    ON emp.staff_id = loc.staff_id
  WHERE emp.user_role = "Employee"
) AS emp
  ON emp.loc_id = mgr_loc.loc_id 
  AND emp.dept_id = mgr_dept.dept_id
WHERE mgr.staff_id = 2
```

Comment: Hey this is along  the right lines, I would like to retrieve all of the individual records, not the count of them. Thanks

Comment: Edited to retrieve all records instead of counts

Comment: That works for every employee in all locations, but if the manager is not assigned to the same location as the employee in that department then it should not be displayed?

Comment: Each location has a set of departments. so location 1 would have 5 departments and location 2 would also. if the manager is in location 1 only they should not see the records of location 2 employees (who are assigned to departments at that location)

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'll have a look at it.